# Help with Jquery Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question in javascript.

Why is this not working:

```
 function scroll_button() { 
        $('div#scrollcase').css('opacity' , 0.3, function() 
        {
            $(this).delay(3500).css('opacity' , 1.0);
        });
    };
```

Is a loop.

Comment: What isn't working? What do you expect it to do and what is it doing?

Comment: The loop is not working. I have 2 divs. Div id scrollcase2 and div id scrollcase1. Every 3500 sec. Must the other div show. Do you understand? Thanks

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to stack overflow.  I'm sorry, but you are going to have to give us a little more than what we've got here.  First, the question text should give us some information so we know if we can even help.  Second "Why is this not working" doesn't really help either.  How is it not working?  How should it work?  What error messages do you get?  What have you already tried?

Comment: there is no overload of this function with 3 parameters

Comment: FWIW, use $('#scrollcase') instead of $('div#scrollcase'). Prefixing with "div" causes the parser to search through all DIVs looking for the one with the correct ID. Referencing the ID directly is much faster. Other than that, what @Niklas said.

Comment: this is a terible way to ask a question. please provide more detail, and your expected results. And in the future, you should title your posts to match the question, not "NEED HELP DEADLINE PROJECT THANKS" please review: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: We're being very close-hungry today, aren't we? Do you guys act the same way towards clients or bosses? It is pretty clear what he is trying to do, and if not, we can ask for more info **without** closing in **less than 3 minutes**, no? What do you think he is doing with `css opacity 0.3 delay css opacity 1`? It reads like a storybook, it's practically pseudocode.

Comment: @Konerak: Would you submit a question in this manner to your boss or client? OP is neither our boss, nor our client, but is asking for free help. The burden is on him to ask clearly and appropriately.

Comment: @patrick: agreed, but even asking questions properly is something one has to learn. I think we should give them the opportunity to. I learnt how to express myself clearer when people edited my questions...

Answer (score 5):

That's not how you use `.css()`.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Try  fadeTo: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
function scroll_button() { 
    $('#scrollcase').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function() 
    {
        $(this).delay(3500).fadeTo('slow' , 1.0);
    });
};
```

Comment: Note that you actually *cannot* use `.css` in combination with `.delay`.

Comment: Interesting; that never occurred to me. Updated my (moot) answer.